# Compare two strings in ANT

Tags: string, ant, echo, newline, equals

Hy!

I have to compare two strings in ANT with `<equals>` task but even if the console show the correctly string, It's doesn't work for my code. This is the code :

```
<echo file="file.txt" append="true">AB${line.separator}</echo>
<echo file="file.txt" append="true">CD${line.separator}</echo>

<loadfile property="content" srcFile="file.txt">
    <filterchain>
      <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.HeadFilter">
       <param name="lines" value="1" />
      </filterreader>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo>${content}</echo>

            <if>
                <equals arg1="${content}" arg2="AB" />
                  <then><echo message="OK"/></then>
                  <else><echo message="not OK"/></else>
            </if>
```

the result of the build is :

```
11:24:23      [echo] AB
11:24:23      [echo] not OK
```

Can you tell me how to fix this please? and thnks :)

Comment: Please note that the "if" task is not a standard ANT feature, it's part of the 3rd party ant-contrib extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `arg2` attribute is missing the line separator. Try this:

```
<equals arg1="${content}" arg2="AB${line.separator}" />
```

Or, even better, try to clean `content` of all line separators.